# How to select the compute the range value of a given date?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this table below. I want to count and select the values within a month range.

[image: table]

Here's my query

```
  select count(*) as c, monthname(file_date) as mn
  from baguio_patrolcase
  where monthname(file_date) between 'January' and 'July'
  group by monthname(file_date)
  order by file_date
```

[image: my output]

What I want to achive is that it will also count and select the values from February an June. How will I do this?

Comment: Remove the `where` clause. If you want just till July, make it `monthname(file_data)<='July'`.

Comment: You are comparing strings - this would place `August` before `July` since A comes before J - remove `monthname` and use month numbers for full control of your filtering - or datetime itself

Comment: @Prerak Sola Thanks but how will I know when to start if ther's no where clause?

Comment: I dont know what will I change to my query. Can you please give examples on this?

Comment: Do you want the data for some particular months or for every month that is present in the table?

Comment: Yes a  I want to get the output likee my output on top but I want to get all the values for the ranges i specify on the month

Answer (score 2):

When you convert the date to a month name, you are comparing *strings*.  Here are two options to do what you want:

```
where month(file_date) between 2 and 6

where file_date >= '2015-02-01' and file_date < '2015-07-01'
```

The second is better, because it allows the engine to use an index on `file_date` (if available).

Also, `between` keeps the end values (it is *inclusive*).  So, if you want February through June, then use those months, rather than 1 and 7.

Comment: Thanks for your responses I am going to check and update you about this.

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood, you can use `in` clause:

```
select count(*) as c, monthname(file_date) as mn
  from baguio_patrolcase
  where monthname(file_date) in('January', 'July')
  group by monthname(file_date)
  order by file_date
```

Add the name of all the required months in the `in` clause.

You can see the [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ec08/2) here.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that there will be an input form in html that you will just provide one for the start and the other for end. That's why i need to get the range of value by having two values only

Comment: Than you need to go with the the first option in the @Gordon's answer. Map the month names with the digits and generate the query with those digits using `between`.